# Saving a Table with a Class Object Parameter in SQLite Database

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I am trying to create a table in a database that includes an object of another class as a parameter. The class I'm trying to use as a parameter is CompletedChecklistData. When I remove CompletedChecklistData from the CompletedChecklist entity, everything works fine, and I can easily insert rows into the table. However, as soon as I add CompletedChecklistData back into the CompletedChecklist entity, I encounter an issue: I can't save any row in the table.

The error message I'm receiving is:
{SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: CompletedChecklist}

Can anyone help me figure out how to save the CompletedChecklist in the database? I specifically want to have CompletedChecklistData as a parameter in the CompletedChecklist entity.

Here are my classes:

```
 [Table(nameof(CompletedChecklist))]
public class CompletedChecklist : BaseDatabaseModel
{
    public string MachineId { get; set; }
    public string WorkerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletedAt { get; set; }
    public CompletedChecklistData CompletedChecklistData { get; set; }
}

public class CompletedChecklistData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChecklistItem> ChecklistItems { get; set; }
}

public class BaseDatabaseModel
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset SyncedToBackendAt { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: sqlite has no idea what `ChecklistItem` is.

Comment: oh, what the solution is?

Comment: you have to create tables to map all of your objects.  This is basic DB design

Comment: So I need to create 3 different tables? ChecklistItem, CompletedChecklist  and  CompletedChecklistData

Comment: generally, that is how you would do it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to Xamarin. What is the best approach for xamarin in this case? Should I create a different table for each entry or should I save JSON string in DB and then SerializeObject I?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and depends on your requirements, there is no universal answer

Comment: what do you suggest? I need to save data locally and later send it back to Api

Comment: I don't care.  Do you actually need to query the data?  If not, why not just serialize to a file instead of a db?